# Scripts has stopped working after apache/php update

Tags: apache-2.2, php, vps, httpd, update

I have updated php to 5.3.1 now some of the scripts hosted on my vps have stopped working.  This includes whmcs and fantastico. All these scripts are showing a blank page. now debugging each and every script will take a lot of time and clients are not happy about it. What do you guys suggest:

- Downgrade
- Debug everything

Comment: Have you checked your Apache logs. I'd think if they all stopped working there will most probably be a common solution between PHP/Apache that should fix them all. Do any PHP scripts work? Could it be an issue with Apache and PHP support in general?

Comment: yes most of wordpress websites are working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick check, look in your error logs see what the problem is. Take appropriate action based on what you find.

If the 'fix' isn't quick, downgrade or recover to a known good position.

Setup a test environment to test/debug the upgrade and make a plan for doing the same in production.

Carry out the plan from above in production.

Repeat the previous two points for all future upgrades.

Comment: there were so many errors some because of php handler like: .htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag' .. probably downgrading is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Turn on php error logs in php.ini 
log_errors = on
error_log = /path/to/file

If there are many different errors, it is probably the best practice to keep on 5.2.x branch.

BTW 5.3.1 is pretty old, better use 5.3.10 for security issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is related to **Ioncube**.

You would need to downgrade or run both php versions in parallel until you get updated versions of the software.

See more at the [WHMCS Forums](http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?t=31054)